# Uncaught ReferenceError: sample_data is not defined in angular 7

Tags: angular, angular7

when an working on angular 7 i getting an issue.

> Uncaught ReferenceError: sample_data is not defined at
>   scripts.js:14256 at dispatch (scripts.js:3) at q.handle (scripts.js:3)
>   at
>   ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask
>   (polyfills.js:2766) at
>   Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask
>   (polyfills.js:2533) at
>   ZoneTask.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneTask.invokeTask
>   [as invoke] (polyfills.js:2841) at invokeTask (polyfills.js:3885) at
>   globalZoneAwareCallback (polyfills.js:3922)

Comment: why don't you check how sample_data is initialized?

Comment: show us ts file , post that script file , so that we can try to help . posting only error wont help brother